# Concatenate multiple separated lists

Tags: python, list, nlp

I am using a large dataset, 20 Newsgroups dataset. I have got 20000 documents and as a result 20000 total lists. and i want to concatenate all of them into one list.

```
['path', 'cantaloupesrvcscmuedu', 'crabapplesrvcscmuedu', 'europaenggtefsdcom', 'howlandrestonansnet', 'nocnearnet', 'uunet', 'olivea', 'sgigate', 'sgiblab', 'adagiopanasoniccom', 'nntpservercaltechedu', 'keith', 'keith', 'ccocaltechedu', 'keith', 'allan', 'schneider', 'newsgroups', 'altatheism', 'subject', 'political', 'atheists', 'messageid', 'gapcaltechedu', 'date', 'apr', 'gmt', 'references', 'gapcaltechedu', 'fidoasdsgicom', 'gapcaltechedu', 'viceicotekcom', 'organization', 'california', 'institute', 'technology', 'pasadena', 'lines', 'nntppostinghost', 'punishercaltechedu', 'bobbe', 'viceicotekcom', 'robert', 'beauchaine', 'writes', 'think', 'people', 'approve', 'death', 'penalty', 'even', 'realizing', 'shortcomings', 'nt', 'make', 'reasonable', 'sole', 'judge', 'reasonability', 'aside', 'revenge', 'merits', 'find', 'capital', 'punishment', 'talking', 'majority', 'people', 'support', 'anyway', 'think', 'revenge', 'fairness', 'people', 'favor', 'punishment']

 ['path', 'cantaloupesrvcscmuedu', 'dasnewsharvardedu', 'huscnewsharvardedu', 'hsdndev', 'wupost', 'uunet', 'newstekcom', 'vice', 'bobbe', 'newsgroups', 'altatheism', 'subject', 'nt', 'innocents', 'die', 'without', 'death', 'penalty', 'messageid', 'viceicotekcom', 'bobbe', 'viceicotekcom', 'robert', 'beauchaine', 'date', 'apr', 'gmt', 'references', 'psilinkcom', 'organization', 'tektronix', 'inc', 'beaverton', 'lines', 'article', 'psilinkcom', 'psilinkcom', 'james', 'f', 'tims', 'writes', 'maintaining', 'classes', 'e', 'even', 'prison', 'seems', 'place', 'innocent', 'people', 'higher', 'risk', 'unjust', 'death', 'would', 'state', 'executed', 'classes', 'e', 'occasional', 'error', 'answer', 'position', 'would', 'indeed', 'place', 'people', 'prison', 'life', 'depends', 'predisposition', 'towards', 'murder', 'also', 'success', 'rate', 'escape', 'therefore', 'ability', 'commit', 'crimes', 'words', 'lifetime', 'imprisonment]

[abused', 'creationist', 'thread', 'real', 'probability', 'abiogenesis', 'messageid', 'nooseecnpurdueedu', 'summary', 'return', 'dead', 'thread', 'keywords', 'bass', 'ale', 'indeed', 'fine', 'brew', 'sender', 'else', 'organization', 'purdue', 'university', 'engineering', 'computer', 'network', 'references', 'ctronnewsctroncom', 'distribution', 'world', 'local', 'date', 'mon', 'apr', 'gmt', 'lines', 'article', 'ctronnewsctroncom', 'king', 'ctroncom', 'john', 'e', 'king', 'writes', 'adpeters]
```

I want to create a list of lists. Is it possible?

Comment: `list1.extend(list2)` will update the list1 with list2 elements

Comment: extend makes it all the words into one list. I would like to have list of list, like,    Big_list = [[list1], [list2], ....., [list20000]]

Comment: How did you get the 20000 list? via api call?

Comment: The dataset contains 20000 documents, hence 20000 lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a list of lists, just use .append on an empty list.

```py
lists = []

lists.append(l1)

lists.append(l2)

lists.append(l3)
```

If you want to concatenate all of them the use this after having the list of lists,

```py
# lists = [l1, l2, l3]
concat = []
for list_ in lists:
    concat += list_
```

Comment: If i put this code i get letters instead of words. ['x', 'r', 'e', 'f', 'c', 'a', 'n', 't', 'a', 'l', 'o', 'u', 'p', 'e', 's', 'r', 'v', 'c', 's', 'c', 'm', 'u', 'e', 'd', 'u', 'p', 'a', 't', 'h', 'c', 'a', 'n', 't', 'a', 'l', 'o', 'u', 'p', 'e', 's', 'r', 'v', 'c', 's', 'c', 'm', 'u', 'e', 'd', 'u', 'c', 'r', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', 's', 'r', 'v', 'c', 's', 'c', 'm', 'u', 'e', 'd', 'u', 'n', 'e', 'w', 's', 's', 'e', 'i', 'c', 'm', 'u', 'e', 'd', 'u', 'c', 'i', 's', 'o', 'h', 'i', 'o', 's', 't', 'a', 't', 'e', 'e', 'd', 'u', 'm', 'a', 'g', 'n', 'u', 's', 'a', 'c', 's',]

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use + like

```
list1 = ["eg",1]
list2 = [1,3]
list3 = list1+list2
```

Comment: it would be proper to give some explanation for your answer to be considered an answer as what, How and Why